# How to return encrypted stream in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, stream

I have a JSON string that I need to return it as an encrypted stream in web api in HttpResponseMessage.
The client then receives the encrypted stream and decrypts it like this.

```
private string str(HttpWebResponse AStream)
{
    string result;
    using (Stream responseStream = AStream.GetResponseStream())
    {
        result = DecryptAesStream(responseStream, Key);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Do I need to encrypt the JSON string first, load it to a filestream but then how do I return it in HttpRepsonseMessage since it takes string as a content?
Any hints what I need to do?

Comment: You want to return a byte array.

Comment: If, for some reason you must return a string, since the result of an encryption algorithm is a byte array, you'll have to encode it. Base64 encoding is often used for this. Keep in mind, on the receiving end it will need to be decoded back to a byte array for the decrypting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
        public byte[] GetEncryptedStream(string jsonData)
        {
            byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            byte[] key = null;//GetKey() //I am assuming you arealy have your Key
            //Call your encrypt function below
            byte[] encryptedDataBytes = encrypt(dataBytes, key); // I am assuming your function returns byte array 
            return encryptedDataBytes;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessage()
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            String jsonString = "your json data";
            byte[] data = GetEncryptedStream(jsonString);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I implement the GetEncryptedStream? My encrypt function takes data as byte: encrypt (byte[] data, byte[] key)

Comment: See updated answer above.. I dont know what your encrypt function returns , so I am assuming it is returning byte[]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I had to modify your code slightly but it helped me fix my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been fixed.